# how can i configure paypal for multi-users in django?

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I have worked on paypal with django. I integrated it with my app with those settings (settings.py):

```
PAYPAL_WPP_USER = '****'
PAYPAL_WPP_PASSWORD = ****'
PAYPAL_WPP_SIGNATURE = '*****'
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = '*****'
```

but what i want to do didn't match with this code. In fact, I have many buyers and many sellers but i think paypal pade only for one money receiver. Any idea with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can process payments on other PayPal accounts other than your own.  You would just need to make sure that the accounts that you will be processing payments for have the service set up on their accounts that you will be using.  You will also need to have them grant the correct permissions to your API username so that you can process a payment on their account.  Then all that you have to do, is in your API call is pass over the variable "SUBJECT" and set the value to the email address of the PayPal account that you are wanting to process the payment for.